# Javascript UI component for defining data mappings

Tags: user-interface

I'm looking for javascript UI component for defining data mappings.

In a previous life I did a lot of work using TIBCO BusinessWorks, and this software had a feature for defining data mappings (Input and output "schema" for structured data, and connecting the fields from one to the other) as a visual interface. It looked like this:

[image: UI for designing a data mapping]

The fields on the right hand side are editable with text for values or formulae referencing input fields. A reference results in a line drawn between them. Behind the scenes I imagine BusinessWorks stored this as an XSLT, although that complexity was never shown directly, so we might think of this as a visual XSLT designer.

I'm hoping to achieve something similar as part of a web form. Surely somebody has built something similar in javascript, and I'm hoping someone might have done so as a re-usable UI component (javascript library / snippet / react component or whatever) But part of why I can't find it is because I'm not sure what we'd even call this thing. "UI component for defining data mappings"? I'm not sure if I'm searching for the right thing.

Comment: This is a question that triggers other questions .. What would be the internal data format ? What would be the underlying language to manage the mappings ? and etc
You may have a look to TIBCO Flogo but I don't think this is what you are looking for.